# How to know if $\log_78 > \log_89$ without using a calculator?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I realize that I lack any numerical intuition for logarithms. For example, when comparing two logarithms like $\log_78$ and $\log_89$, I have to use the change-of-base formula and calculate the values with a calculator in order to determine which of the two is larger.

Can anyone demonstrate an algebraic/analytic method to find out which of the two is larger without using a calculator?

Comment: $\log_x(x+1)=\log(x+1)/\log(x)$ is decreasing for $x>1$ but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: @lhf: $\frac{\log(x + 2) / \log (x + 1)}{\log(x + 1) / \log(x)} = \frac{\log(x + 2) \log(x)}{\log(x + 1)^2}$. Now $\frac{(x + 2)x}{(x + 1)^2} < 1$ (rectangle areas), and since $\log$ is concave, the same must hold for when you apply $\log$ to each factor.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$\log_7 8 = 1 + \log_7 (8 / 7) > 1 + \log_7 (9/8) > 1 + \log_8(9/8) = \log_8 9$

Comment: brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $f(x)=\frac{\log(x+1)}{\log(x)}$ has the same sign as $\frac{\log x}{x+1}-\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}$ which is negative if $x>1$ since $x\mapsto x\log{x}$ is increasing.

Of course, this method does not apply for arbitrary 7,8,9. For example $\log_35$ and $\log_23$ are quite close and proving that one is bigger than the other is not so easy. The only elegant way I know is some kind of trick. (Enjoy this entertaining exercise! Spoiler below.)

> Prove that $\log_35 < \frac32 < \log_23$.

Comment: I don't get why the two expressions have the same sign. But actually I'm looking for a general method to compare the sizes of two logarithms. So the numbers 7,8,9 in the question are actually arbitrary.

Comment: @dragoncharmer: $f'(x)\big(\log x\big)^2=\frac{\log x}{x+1}-\frac{\log(x+1)}x$, and $\big(\log x\big)^2>0$ for $x\ne 1$.

Comment: interesting exercise. it seems to me wallace's method fails here.

Comment: btw in the exercise, 1/2 should be 3/2.

Comment: @dragoncharmer: oh, thanks.

Comment: I think I found a more direct proof, see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:

$$\log_78 > \log_89 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\log_87} > \log_89 \Leftrightarrow 1> \log_87 \log_89 $$

Now, by AM-GM

$$\log_87 \log_89 \leq (\frac{\log_87+ \log_89}{2})^2=(\frac{\log_863}{2})^2< (\frac{\log_864}{2})^2=1$$

**In general** If $ab < c^2$ and $\log_b c >0$ you have

$$\log_ca \log_cb \leq (\frac{\log_ca+ \log_cb}{2})^2< 1$$

and thus

$$\log_ca < \log_bc \,.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function  $ f(x)=\log_x(x+1)$

This is a decreasing function and hence $\log_n(n+1) >\log_m(m+1)$ for $n < m$
and hence $\log_78 > \log_89$.

---

$f(x)$ is decreasing because, $f'(x)$ comes out to be negative,

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(x)}$$

$$f '(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)\ln x} + \ln(x+1).\frac{-1}{{(\ln x)}^2}.\frac{1}{x}$$

$$f '(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)$$

and since $f(x)<1$ for $x \in \mathbb R^+$, we have $f'(x)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):=\log_x(x+1)$, with $x>1$. Then
$$f(x)=\log_x x+\log_x\left(1+\frac1x\right)=1+\frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{\ln x}.$$
Now, as $x$ increases, $1+1/x$ strictly decreases, as does its logarithm; at the same time, the denominator $\ln x$ increases. Hence $f$ is a strictly decreasing function.It follows that
$$\log_78>\log_89.$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $x>1$, we set
$$\tag{1}
y=1-\frac{1}{x}, \quad z=1+\frac{1}{x}
$$
so that
$$\tag{2}
x-1=xy, \quad x+1=xz, \quad yz=1-\frac{1}{x^2}.
$$
Notice that
$$\tag{3}
0<y, yz <1, \quad 1< z <2
$$
Now
\begin{eqnarray}\tag{4}
\log(x-1)&=&\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)\cr
\log(x+1)&=&\log(xz)=\log(x)+\log(z)\cr
\log(x-1)\log(x+1)&=&\log^2(x)+[\log(y)+\log(z)]\log((x)+\log(y)\log(z)\cr
&=&\log^2(x)+\log(yz)\log(x)+\log(y)\log(z)
\end{eqnarray}
Thanks to the fact that $x>1$ together with (3) we have
$$\tag{5}
\max(\log(y), \log(yz) )<0, \quad \min(\log(x), \log(z))>0
$$
Combining (5) to the last equation in (4), we obtain
$$
\log(x-1)\log(x+1)<\log^2(x)
$$
or equivalently
$$\tag{6}
\log_{x-1}(x)> \log_x(x+1) \quad \forall x>1
$$
Setting $x=8$, we get the desired inequality.